# How do I handle right click on RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

How do I handle right click in RichTextBox in C#?

For example:

When I right-click mouse over a RichTextBox the program will display a MessageBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to catch `Mouse_Down` event, not `Mouse_Click` as follows:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("you got it!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the [MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.mouseclick.aspx) event and check the `MouseEventArgs.Button` property to see which button was clicked.

What have you tried for yourself?

Comment: @HassanShatnawi it [does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.mouseclick.aspx): _"The RichTextBox control does not raise a Click event for right clicks. The **MouseClick event** provides the functional equivalent."_

Answer (score 0):

click RichTextBox in design mode .Right click and select properties and Then navigate to MouseDown Event.Double click that event and you will be directed to Code behind page and there you can write your code.